# Save ggplot2 figure via rpy2 into a Python buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, ggplot2, rpy2

I'm trying to save the output of a `ggplot2` *R* object created using `rpy2` into a buffer controlled by Python.

I'm able to do this using `matplotlib` but I cannot seems to do it with *ggplot2* via `rpy2`.

---

In `matplotlib.pyplot`, this can be accomplished with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
import numpy

def test_save():
    x = numpy.linspace(-5, 5)
    y = 3*x + 2
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, f)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf, format = 'png')
    return buf
```

---

`ggplot2` attempt:

```
import io
import numpy   
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from pandas import DataFrame
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2


def test_ggplot2_save():

    x = numpy.linspace(-5, 5)
    y = 3*x + 2
    df = DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

    gp = ggplot2.ggplot(df)
    pp = (gp 
      + ggplot2.aes_string(x='x', y='y')
      + ggplot2.geom_point()
      + ggplot2.labs(title="MY DATA", x='x', y='y'))
    # pp.plot()

    buf = io.BytesIO()

    robjects.r.ggsave(filename=buf, plot=pp, width=200, height=120, unit='mm')
```

Error:

> NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type ''

I was trying to use the [`rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2.GGPlot.save`](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/graphics.html#rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2.GGPlot.save) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's `ggplot2::ggsave` is expecting a string specifying a path (relative or absolute) as an argument for the parameter `filename`. For example `"/this/is/my/figure.png"`.

A Python `BytesIO` object is quite different. It is an in-memory binary stream (roughly Python object that behaves like a (binary) file).

If using `ggsave` is not an absolute requirement, consider using
`rpy2.robjects.lib.grdevices.render_to_bytesio()`. This is the function that makes the following display inline figures in the Jupyter notebook:

```
from rpy2.ipython.ggplot import image_png
# pp is your ggplot2 figure
display(image_png(pp))
```

Comment: the main need is to be able to store the graph inside of a buffer. Will this be able to do that?

Comment: Yes: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/d5d60e9a0f684c27015fa29c26bbb7fd75863bc2/rpy/robjects/lib/grdevices.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#grdevices.py-66